# Unlimited file upload depending on infrastructure

Tags: angular, .net-core

Requirement : File being uploaded from angular UI and sent to database with the help of dot net core api . How can we upload unlimited file from front end and also this upload task need to run in background so user can go anywhere in the webpage . once the upload is done then notification will come like "your upload is done ".
Also I want to resume the upload file if I need

Comment: How is this related to the SQL _language_? "_Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL._"

Comment: thanks @jarlh for informing . in the question I mentioned SQL because the files when they are uploaded are stored to SQL DB by using the filestream .

Comment: If you need SQL assistance, show us your SQL code and describe its problem.

Comment: I have removed the SQL tag now . I need the assistance on angular and dot net core only .